# Creating arbitrary directory in kickstart before %post

Tags: centos, rhel, rpm, kickstart, mkdir

One of the non-OS packages that I need to install via kickstart config requires a pre-existing (non-standard) directory, is there a way to create arbitrary directory before %post in kickstart?
Modifying the rpm to remove this requirement is not an option but I'd like to get the package installed as part of kickstart.
Thanks.

Comment: When do you install the package?  When does it need the directory to exist?  Can't you just create the directory using `mkdir -p ...` in the `%post` section?

Comment: I'm installing the packages as part of %packages in the kickstart config, so the directory needs to exists before this stage but after all the partitions are created.

Answer (score 1):

kickstart allows you to have a [%pre-install](https://github.com/rhinstaller/pykickstart/blob/master/docs/kickstart-docs.rst#pre-install-script) script, which is further on than `%pre`, and has the root of the filesystem ready and mounted at `/mnt/sysimage`.  So to create dir `/abc/def` you should try

```
%pre-install
mkdir -p /mnt/sysimage/abc/def
%end
```

---

If your anaconda doesnt support this yet, you could try this hack: create a user whose home directory is the directory you need. Eg

```
user --name=hackforrpm --shell=/sbin/nologin --homedir=/abc/def
```

Comment: Adding %pre-install section to my kickstart script makes it bombed out, looks like that option is not recognized. I also couldn't find any reference to it in RHEL guide https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/s1-kickstart2-preinstallconfig.html

Comment: I'm running anaconda 13.21.215. The error is: 

There was a problem reading from line *line number where %pre-install is inserted* of the kickstart file
install exited abnormally [1/1]
The system will be rebooted when you press Ctrl-C or Ctrl-Alt-Delete

Comment: ok. I added a possible hack using the `user` option to my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately that hack won't work since the user creation only happens AFTER package installation (i.e at post-install). Looks like the option that works is to create a dummy package that does nothing but create the required directories and put it before the packages that needs it in the %packages section.

Comment: I suppose that makes sense. Your mini rpm is a good clean solution.